# Constructing class with two members

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11

Lets say we've got the following:

(1) Class `C` which has two members `X1 x1` and `Y1 y1`.
(2) `C` has no default constructor, but does have the constructor `C(Z)`.
(3) A class `X1` that has no default constructor, but the constructor `X1(X2)`.
(4) A class `Y1` that has no default constructor, but the constructor `Y1(Y2)`.
(5) A function `f(Z)`, which returns `std::pair<X2, Y2>`

Lets say `f(z) -> std::pair<X2, Y2>{x2,y2}`.

How do I write the class `C` such that member `X1 x1 == X1(x2)` and `Y1 y1 == Y1(y2)` after construction?

Comment: ...and the idea is you don't want to call `f` twice?

Comment: In this case, `f` isn't pure, so calling `f` twice results in two different inconsistent results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11, you can add a delegating constructor of `C`:

```
class C {
  X1 x1; Y1 y1;
public:
  C(Z z): C(f(Z)) {}
private:
  C(std::pair<X2, Y2> p): x1(p.first), x2(p.second) {}
};
```

If you can't use delegating constructors, the only way to do this is to move the members to helper class `B` and write `C` inheriting from `B` and adding the constructor from `Z`:

```
struct B {
  X1 x1; Y1 y1;
  B(std::pair<X2, Y2> p): x1(p.first), x2(p.second) {}
};
class C: private B {
  public:
  C(Z z): B(f(Z)) {}
};
```